# Creating Directories on a local machine

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

Is there any option create directory in a local PC with a connected database name in PL/SQL?

```
host mkdir C:\TestDir\ || select name from v$database;
```

Output should look like: C:\TestDir\MySampleOraDatabaseName

Thanks!

Comment: PL/SQL runs within the database, on a **database server**. Now you'd want that database server to "break" security protocols, reach your own PC via network and create a directory on its hard disk. Instead of suggesting a "solution", perhaps you should describe the "problem" so that someone might suggest a proper solution. Because, what you want is anything but.

Comment: `host` is a client command, not PL/SQL, or even SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a substitution variable, set from a query; this is from SQL*Plus but the same thing should work in PL/SQL Developer:

```
column x_name new_value y_name
select name as x_name from v$database;
host mkdir C:\TestDir\&y_name
```

The real `name` value is given the alias `x_name`, and the `column ... new_value` clause makes that value available as `&y_name`. (You can choose your own aliases/names of course.)

Or include the full path in the variable:

```
column x_path new_value y_path
select 'C:\TestDir\' || name as x_path from v$database;
host mkdir "&y_path"
```

I've enclosed the full path in quotes in case your real directory includes spaces.

You can then use the same substitution variable in spool commands etc.

What you *can't* do is have a directory on your local client machine which is the target for a database directory object - those have to be on, or at least visible to, the server(s) the database is running on. That might not be your aim though.